# How to validate the number in Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, mvvmcross

I have the Xamarin.Android project with using MVVMCross. I work with Visual Studio.

```
Windows 10 64 Pro
Visual Studio 2017
```

I need to create the text area for the number input and integrate basic validation (is this a number?) In case of error user should see the error message.

I have created the layout of this elements. Area for the number and for the error message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:phoneNumber="true"
        local:MvxBind="Text UserNumber" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/incorrectNumber"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#F44336"
        local:MvxBind="Text IncorrectNumber" />
```

And here is `NumberViewModel.cs`:

```
using MvvmCross.Platform.Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using My.project.Core.Models;

namespace My.project.Core.ViewModels
{
    class NumberViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _userNumber;
        private string _incorrectNumber;

        public string UserNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _userNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _userNumber = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.UserNumber);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IncorrectNumber);
            }
        }

        public string IncorrectNumber
        {
            get
            {
                if (UserNumber is Int16 || UserNumber is Int32) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Incorrect phone number";
                }
            }

        }

    }
 }
```

But for some reason, I can't see the error message if I type non-numeric characters in this area. It should appear under the number.

[image]

I'm the very newbie in MVVMCross and a little bit confused. Please, help

UPD. I have added changes from fmaccaroni advice.
Now the error message is always here. Even if the area contains only digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings are wrong, they should be `local:MvxBind="Text UserNumber"` and `local:MvxBind="Text IncorrectNumber"` check the [docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding).

And unless you are using [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) package (which I'd recommend you to use) you should call `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IncorrectNumber)` inside the setter of UserNumber, i.e. after `_userNumber = value;` in order to inform the View that some property (`IncorrectNumber`) has changed from the ViewModel

Update

You should also change your validation in `IncorrectNumber` setter as @mrisek said.
It should be like

`public string IncorrectNumber => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserNumber) && int.TryParse(UserNumber, out int n) ? null : "Incorrect phone number" ;`

If you use the `is` operator, it compares if the object is of that `Type` which is not clearly.
By the way remember the length of an Int32 if you want a higher number you should use Int64 or make the validation with Regex: `Regex.IsMatch(UserNumber, @"^\d+$")`

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my code and tested it. Now the error message is always here. Even if the area contains only digits. (I add the code changes in the post)

Comment: You lack `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IncorrectNumber)` in the UserNumber setter, i.e. after `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.UserNumber);`. This RaisePropertyChanged will let the view know that the `IncorrectNumber` has changes and therefore it will enter again in the `get` updating your view. Btw you don't need a setter in the `IncorrectNumber` when it is never being set

Comment: Well, I did it. But the error is  still here. I see it even if the area contains only digits yet. Maybe, something wrong with the converter?

Comment: @NaSt updated the answer with the IncorrectNumber validation

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! The last question: At first, the text area is empty and IncorrectNumber shows me the error. How can I add the exception for empty UserNumber?

Comment: @NaSt just verify whether it is null or empty also. I've updated the answer with that too. Remember to accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this way, but I still can see the error with the empty UserNumber :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163274/discussion-between-fmaccaroni-and-nast).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve it like this:

```
int numb;
if (!int.TryParse(UserNumber, out numb) && UserNumber.Length != 0) 
{
    return "Incorrect phone number";
}
```

Comment: This solution works! Only one question. At first, the text area is empty and IncorrectNumber shows me the error. How can I add the exception for empty UserNumber?

Comment: I edited my answer so the error message won't show up if input's length is equal to zero.